# Trying to allow unlimited words separated by spaces

Tags: regex

I have a regex to only allow hyphens and apostrophes in a person's name and disallow all numeric and special characters.  Right now its limiting it to 2 names but I want to allow unlimited names, just only allow hyphens and apostrophes.

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\-\+\s]\s*[a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)\s*$
```

I need it to allow: Dennis Dennis's Dennis-s Dennis  etc..  Right now it only allows 2 words and returns a non-match on the 3rd word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you had explained:

```
^\s*               #Match 0+ whitespace
[a-zA-Z]+          #Match 1 or more alpha characters
(                  #Capturing Group 1
    (                 #Capturing Group 2
        [\'\-\+\s]       #Match one of these characters.
        \s*              #Match 0+ whitespace
        [a-zA-Z]         #Match one alpha character
    )?                #0 or 1 of Group 2
    [a-zA-Z]*         #0+ alpha characters
)                  #End Group 1
\s*                #Then 0+ whitespace.
$
```

There is quite a lot of improvement you could do, but I think just putting an extra group around the whole thing with a + would be the smallest change you could do:

```
^(\s*[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\-\+\s]\s*[a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)\s*)+$
```

Answer (score 1):

it would appear that you are writting your regEx backwards in order to allow unlimited names. instead you should check the names to make sure they dont contain any special characters

```
var myname="whatever";
if ((/\$|\/|\^|-/, "g").exec(myname)){
    alert("this has special characters";
}else{
    alert "this does not";
}
```

Comment: Not understanding this one as its not in a regex format I can use.. :(

Comment: i always write code in javascript by default without even looking at the tags... my mistake,  stupid brain

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options.

1. **Simply allow only the valid characters**.  The downside is that the arrangements may be weird, the upside is that you aren't overly strict and possible reject something valid you hadn't thought of.

   ```
   ^[A-Za-z'+\-\s]+$
   ```
2. **Create a repeating group of a valid name pattern**.  This seems to be what you are trying to do, though you haven't specified *exactly* what a valid name is.  Here's an example, based on your example:

   ```
   /^\s*(?:\s?[A-Za-z]+(?:[\-'+][a-zA-Z]+)?)+\s*$/
   ```

   This pattern says: *start, 0 or more whitespace, then 1 or more of the group: (optional space (for second and later words), 1 or more A-Z, and an optional group: (1 dash, apostrophe, or plus and then 1 or more A-Z)), 0 or more whitespace, end*